# Buffer overflow vulnerabilities with char[ ] and char *

Tags: c, arrays, char, buffer, overflow

When I perform a strcpy to a char[]:

```
char buf[100];

strcpy(buf[], largeInput);
```

If largeInput is longer than 100 bytes we have a buffer overflow.

However I have a question, if `buf`, instead of being a `char[]` is a `char` pointer, would there be a buffer overflow as well?

I think, if `largeInput` is long enough, when copied to `char *buf`, it could reach a memory zone of another variable. However I'm not sure this is a vulnerability.

I used flawfinder and it accused such code of being a buffer overflow vulnerability

```
char *buf;

strcpy(buf, largeInput);
```

I'm just not sure if it is a false positive or not.

Comment: `strcpy(buf[], largeInput);`??????

Comment: @SouravGhosh its just an example, the code is not just that.  largeInput is some user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we see *just* this part of code

```
char *buf;
strcpy(buf, largeInput);
```

it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because, you're trying to write into unitialized pointer.

even if you have allocated memory to `buf` previously, and the content of `largeInput` is more that that of the allocated space in `buf`, then , yes, it is UB, too. There is no way `buf` gets *auto adjusted*.

However, FWIW, you can always use `strdup()` to be on safer side.

Comment: The code is not just that, I just put the part I was interested in. Let's pretend the pointer is initialized and largeInput is some large input provided to the program :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support arbitrary sized inputs allocate memory for largeInput based on the size.

```
char* largeInput = "very long string...";
char *buf = malloc(strlen(largeInput) + 1);
strcpy(buf, largeInput);
/* do something with buf */
free(buf);
```